# Live streaming to darwin server - android

Tags: android, darwin

I have installed Darwin Streaming Server on a machine running linux and I am using a RTSP client from **[libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming)**. The library seems to be working fine with Wowza media server but with Darwin
 I am stuck at `ANNOUNCE request` to which server is responding with null `session_id`.
Is this the normal scenario with Darwin Server or am I missing something?

I am thinking may be the Request is malformed. Please correct me if I am wrong or
suggest me otherwise.

Here's the ANNOUNCE request:

```
ANNOUNCE rtsp://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:80/mystream.sdp RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 1
Content-Length: 288
Content-Type: application/sdp 
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 null
s=Unnamed
i=N/A
c=IN IP4 xxx.xxx.x.xxx
t=0 0
a=recvonly
m=audio 5004 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 mpeg4-generic/8000
a=fmtp:96 streamtype=5; profile-level-id=15; mode=AAC-hbr; config=1588; SizeLength=13; IndexLength=3; IndexDeltaLength=3;
a=control:trackID=0
```

Comment: did you get the solution. i Am not been able to conncet with Darwin using libstreaming